# Creating a session beans without putting Remote or Local Annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

When I create an EJB and doesn't use  neither `Remote` or `Local` annotation then the bean could be access only from local or even from remote? I mean which is the default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bean implements a single interface except Serializable etc it is treated as the only (local) business interface of the bean. (EJB 3.1 4.9.7)

If the bean does not implement any appropriate interface it is treated as a bean with a no interface view.

If it implements multiple interfaces the business interfaces must be defined using the respective annotations or the deployment descriptor.